# PHP string contains $ and incorrectly recognizes variable

Tags: php, string, variables

Basically I'm sending a formatted string to a PHP script via POST

So say I have the string... "abcdef$ghikl" it will recognize $ghikl as a variable...

Is there any ways to tell PHP that no variables exist within this string?

I know how to hard code it, you just use "'", but since the string is being sent to the script, I don't know what to do...

Thanks guys

For the scope of the question, all the code that's really needed is this:

```
$string = $_POST['string'];
// a couple strcmp's here, just to see if the string == ""
$array = explode("+", $string);
```

Comment: Use single quote `'` instead of double quotes `"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping the $

```
"abcdef\$ghikl"
```

Comment: is there an alternative? given the design of my application, that isn't a very efficient option...

Comment: If the dollar sign is in a string in a POST variable, then it will not recognize it as a variable. This only happens with string literals.

Comment: well now I'm baffled... it's weird because when I remove all the '$' from the string and send it via post, everything works great... so that *has* to be the problem...

Comment: Are you sending the string from javascript? If so you can just remove the dollar signs before you send it, `str.replace( /\$/g, "\\$" )`

Comment: yeah it's through cocoa... thanks for the help I think I'll just add slashes before all the $ signs :/

Answer (score 0):

PHP won't see that as a variable unless you eval() it. Can you show us your code?